# How do I share a Google Cloud SQL privately outside its region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Not finding any solid answers that fit within the scope of my question.

I have a custom VPC established to allow communication between my SQL server and instance groups. My issues are limited connectivity to the SQL server from instances within the same region as the server itself.

Basically, I created a Cloud SQL instance within us-east region.

When I create a VM Instance within the same region as the SQL instance, I have no issues connecting to its private IP.

```
mysql -h{PRIVATE_IP} -uroot
```

However, running this same command from an instance in a different region results in a timeout. Both instances are configured the exact same and within the same VPC network.

I let Google allocate IP address pool for me when I created the IP. Created the private network connection within my custom VPC settings and tried tutorials provided in the Cloud Console documentation itself with no luck.

Any help getting me on the right track would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your question needs specific details on exactly what is connecting (detail your desired network configuration and layout). VPCs can peer, Cloud SQL Proxy can connect to private instances, VPNs can span networks and providers. There are many options that depend on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine#connecting_using_private_ip), if you want to connect Cloud SQL from a Compute Engine instance using private IP, your instance must be in the same region as your Cloud SQL instance.

Keep in mind that [your Cloud SQL instances are not created in your VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip), those are created in a Google internal VPC network that then is peered to your VPC network.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So it's impossible to connect to a Cloud SQL instance from a Compute Engine instance that's not in the same region?

Comment: Yes, currently, having the GCE instance in the [same region](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine#connecting_using_private_ip) as your Cloud SQL instance is a requirement in order to connect Cloud SQL from a Compute Engine instance using private IP.

Comment: Unfortunate, however you've answered my question so thank you!